# SQLAlchemy eating RAM

Tags: python, memory, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to import some XML data into my MySQL database after processing it with Python. To keep things simple, I'm doing it all from one script that uses SQLAlchemy to access my database.

The XML file has about 80,000 entries and I process it using `xml.etree.cElementTree`'s `iterparse` method and delete nodes after I use them to keep my memory usage at around 20mb.

Once I include SQLAlchemy and start adding things into the database, my memory usage rises by about 10mb per second until the script exhausts all of my memory and the OS kills it.

Here's basically what my code looks like:

```
index = 0

for element in iterate_xml():
    ...

    index += 1

    session.add(Model(**data))

    if index % 1000 == 0:
        session.flush()
        session.commit()
```

I'm not sure what else to try. A periodic `.flush()` and `.commit()` do help a little bit, but they don't fix the problem.

Is SQLAlchemy not the right tool for this task?

---

I setup SQLAlchemy like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=False)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)
session = Session()
```

And my table looks like this:

```
columns = []

for name, datatype in structure.iteritems():
    if isinstance(datatype, int):
        datatype = String(datatype or 20)

    column = Column(name, datatype)
    columns.append(column)

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
table = Table('table_name', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    *columns
)

metadata.drop_all(engine)
metadata.create_all(engine)

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_name'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'autoload_with': engine
    }
```

`structure` is a dictionary that maps column names to data types (it's generated from the XML):

```
structure = {
    'column_name': SQLAlchemyDataType,
    ...
}
```

Comment: after `session.commit()` do also [`session.explunge_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge_all)

Comment: @van: That sounds like it should help, but sadly it doesn't change anything. The memory usage plateaus for a little bit but keeps on rising.

Comment: I am wondering if this is the `XML` part (and not the `SA` part) that grows memory usage.

Comment: this doesn't sound like the issue is on the SQLAlchemy side.  What does your Model object do ?  can you provide a working example ?   what happens if you look at the changes to gc.get_objects(), what kinds of objects are actually being added ?

Comment: @van: I specifically re-wrote the XML part to use very little RAM. The script takes about 20 minutes to run and while it's iterating over the XML data, my RAM usage stays constant (it fluctuates by 20mb). Once the SQLAlchemy part kicks in, the memory usage just starts growing.

Comment: @zzzeek: The script is fairly lengthy, but I've updated my question with the relevant code and an explanation of the variables.

Comment: You'd need to illustrate specific datatypes and their usage that are growing memory.   the autoload=True and the not-displayed "structure" tells us nothing about what kinds of data and datatypes are actually being used.  Basically nothing can be determined without an exact reproduction case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a SQLAlchemy-only version of your code.   Testing in 0.7 and 0.8, it doesn't leak any memory, which is not a surprise to me because we have over a dozen tests under continuous integration to ensure nothing leaks under many scenarios.    So first step is to confirm this script doesn't leak for you, then try to figure out what changes between this script and yours to produce a test case that actually shows the leaking memory.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)

e = create_engine("sqlite:///somefile.db")

Base.metadata.create_all(e)

session = Session(e)

for index in xrange(10000000):
    session.add(Model(data="data %d" % index))

    if index % 1000 == 0:
        print "flushing... %d" % index
        session.flush()
        session.commit()
```

It's important to note of course, those issues where SQLAlchemy has leaked memory in the past.  Here's a recent history of leaks fixed:

0.7.8 - the most recent.  The leak fixed here only occurred when using:  1. the C extensions, 2. the pyodbc driver, during certain result fetch operations (not all of them)

0.6.6 - the "Decimal" result processor in the C extensions had a leak.

0.6.6 - the SQLSoup extension was identified as having a potential leak if used to select rows in certain ways (SQLSoup is now it's own project)

0.5.5 - fixed potential memory leak when objects would be unpickled and placed back into a Session

0.5.4 - major improvements to the Session's memory usage were made.   You definitely want to be well past this version.

Comment: This is pretty much what my code looks like, except that I'm using `String`, `Integer`, `PickleType` and a format similar to `DateTime`. I'll exclude those data types one-by-one and see what object is causing problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I feel absolutely stupid right now. It was my XML parsing code. Thank you for taking the time to write this up, I really appreciate it!